# Modifying linux for different boards

Tags: linux

There are different linux available for different boards- called "linux ports"

For example a (uc)linux port for STM32F4291 Discovery kit, a linux port for Beagleboard and so on.

I want to know what are the major **differences and similarities** between these ports?

I am asking this because say, I want to take port-A for Board 1, and modify it to run on board 2.  Once I know the differences/similarities I will have a better idea of this modification required.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to know what are the major differences and similarities between these ports?

You would have to look at them individually.  If you are talking about just the kernel, the easiest way to do that would be to get the corresponding vanilla source and diff the two trees.

If you are talking about an entire distribution (i.e. kernel + userland), I think these are usually based on an existing x86 distro, recompiled for the platform.  They are probably more-or-less identical after that.  WRT diff'ing the kernel source in this case, keep in mind distros often use their own slightly patched versions.